# how to visualize interactive line chart in R using ggplot having date

Tags: r, interactive

I have following data set and I want to visualize it in Line chart or any thing using ggplot in R  by library(plotly) and add add_trace function

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18049, 18050, 18051, 18052), class = "Date"), 
    x = c(23L, 0L, 54L, 62L), y = c(45L, 72L, 10L, 21L), Total = c(68L, 
    72L, 156L, 83L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I want to visualize data, x, y columns in line chart using ggplot in R. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this `tidyverse` and `plotly` approach. You have to first reshape your data to long and then you can plot. Here the code. I have used dummy data similar to that posted:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
#Code
#Prepare data
df1 <- df %>%
  #First format date
  mutate(Date=as.Date(Date,'%d/%m/%Y')) %>%
  #Reshape
  pivot_longer(cols = -1)%>%
  #Filter out total
  filter(name!='Total')
#Plot
plot_ly(df1, 
        x = ~Date,
        y = ~value,
        name=~name,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Date = c("02/06/2019", "03/06/2019", "04/06/2019", 
"05/06/2019"), x = c(23L, 0L, 54L, 62L), y = c(45L, 72L, 102L, 
21L), Total = c(68L, 72L, 156L, 83L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

In that way you can reach an interactive plot. If you reshape your data you could avoid using plenty of `add_trace()` functions. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a second way without reshaping the data and directly with the `plotly` package.

```
plot_ly(df, x = ~Date) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~x, name = "x", type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~y, name = "y", type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
```

Or just simple a plot in `ggplot` in combination with the function `ggplotly`.

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = x, color = "a")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y, color = "b")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Colors", 
                     values = c("a" = "blue", "b" = "red"))

ggplotly(g)
```